# How can the code in a views.py be tested?

Tags: django, django-views

```
def post(self, request, *args , **kwargs):
        form = self.form(request.POST)
        template_name= "spotify_calls/display.html"
    
        if form.is_valid():
            cleaned = form.cleaned_data["SpotifyForm"]
            
            SpotifyAPI(client_data=" xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx“, client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            data = SpotifyAPI.search(self, query=cleaned , search_type="artiste")
```

I want to determine if the method, `SpotifyAPI.search()`, actually worked and returned data in the data variable before I render it on a template. Expecting a dictionary in the data variable. Is there a way I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check what you want inside the data:

```
if 'what_I_want' inside data.keys():  # or data.values() depending on what you want
    render(...)
```